# i want to get the ipaddress of a server that is connected to the same network as i am,but i keep getting an error so now inputting it manually

Tags: c#, wpf, sockets

whenever i try to get the ipaddress of  a server that is connected to the same network as i am i keep getting an error. so i a am forced to input the ip manually.

```
        string number;
        FileDialog fd;

        byte[] filebyte;

    private void Browse_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        fd = new OpenFileDialog();
        fd.DefaultExt = ".png";
        string sent = "Sent";
        Nullable<bool> result = fd.ShowDialog();
        if (result == true)
        {string filename = fd.FileName;
         file.Text = filename;
         FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(file.Text = fd.FileName);
         number = fi.Name + "." + fi.Length;
            database db = new database();
            db.Insert(filename, sent);
         Task.Run(() =>{
         TcpClient clients = new TcpClient("localhost", 8888);
         StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(clients.GetStream());
         sw.WriteLine(number);
         sw.Flush(); });
         }
         }
        private void Share_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e){
                 TcpClient client = new TcpClient("localhost", 8889);
                 Stream s = client.GetStream();
                 filebyte = File.ReadAllBytes(fd.FileName);
                 s.Write(filebyte, 0, filebyte.Length);
        //client.Close();
                 MessageBox.Show("file transferred");

                 }
                 }
                 }
```

so i tried to get the host of the ipaddress and insert it in the above code where ip is localhost. but this code is not working

```
         string ip;
    private void  GetIP()
    {
        string strHostName = "";
        strHostName = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName();
        IPHostEntry ipEntry = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(strHostName);
        IPAddress[] addr = ipEntry.AddressList;
       ip= addr[0].ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the complete exception details as text so we have a starting point to help.

Comment: okay my bad i have edited it

Comment: What do you mean by "but this code is not working"? Please tell us what your expected and what yout got. Also, what does the question have to do with WPF?

Comment: okay there i have edited it